# Not-a-number appearing in a Fortran CFD code

Tags: floating-point, fortran, nan

I am trying to solve the Euler 1-dimensional equations of fluid flow through a double convergent-divergent nozzle.

This is my code in its entirety:

```
module constants

double precision ::GAM, GAMM1 ,rkconst(4),conA,conB,conC,conK,R, T0
double precision, allocatable :: xc(:),xf(:),Sc(:),Sf(:), Scp(:)

end module constants

Program Euler1d
  
  use constants

  Implicit None

  double precision, allocatable :: U(:,:),U0(:,:),cell_flux(:,:),P(:)

  double precision :: XMIN, XMAX, DX, DT,TIME

  double precision :: UCL(3),UCR(3),UPL(3),UPR(3), NORM,Flux(3)

  integer          :: i, j, k, NX,NXC,NTIME, NTIMETOT

R = 287.05;

T0 = 276;

GAM=1.4; GAMM1=GAM - 1

conA= 0.408

conB= 0.93

conC= 1.07

conK= 0.17

!Define runge kutta constants

  rkconst(1) = 0.1084d0

  rkconst(2) = 0.2602d0

  rkconst(3) = 0.5052d0

  rkconst(4) = 1.d0

!Input Parameters

  NTIMETOT = 5000            ! Total timesteps

  XMIN = 0.0                 ! XMIN

  XMAX = 2.0                 ! XMAX

  DX = 1.0E-2                ! DX

  DT = 1.0E-6                ! DT

!Finite Volume Scheme-Nodes represent faces

!Number of points/faces

  NX = int((XMAX-XMIN)/DX)

!Calculate new DX for accurate division by NX

  DX = (XMAX-XMIN)/(NX-1)

  !write (*,*) 'New DX =', DX

!Number of cell centers

  NXC= NX -1

! 0: represents boundary cell at start and NXC+1 boundary cell at end

! U is the solution vector (Dens, Dens *U, Dens *E), U0 the vector after the 1st Runge-Kutta step

! cell_flux is the sum of the fluxes for each cell

  allocate (U(3,0:NXC+1),U0(3,0:NXC+1))

  allocate (cell_flux(1:3,0:NXC+1))
  
  allocate (P(1:NXC))
 
allocate(xf(1:NX))
allocate(xc(1:NXC+1))
allocate(Sf(1:NX))
allocate(Sc(0:NXC+1))
allocate(Scp(1:NXC+1))

do i=1,NX
xf(i)= XMIN + (i-1)*DX
xc(i)= xf(i) + DX/2
Sf(i)= conK+conA*((xf(i)-conC)**2)*((xf(i)-conC)**2-conB**2)
Sc(i)= conK+conA*((xc(i)-conC)**2)*((xc(i)-conC)**2-conB**2)
Scp(i)=4*conA*(xc(i)-conC)**3-(2*conA*conB**2)*(xc(i)-conC)

  open (2,file='areas.dat')

  !write(2,'(a)') '#index, x of face, x of center, face, center, prime'
  
  write(2,'(6(e28.17,1x))') i, xf(i), xc(i), Sf(i), Sc(i), Scp(i)

!write (*,*) i, Sc(i)

enddo
Sc(0)= Sc(1)

write (2,*)

TIME=0

!Set initial conditions

  call ic
  
   !write (*,*) 'U initial is', U(1:3,0:NXC+1)

  do NTIME = 1, NTIMETOT

     k=1

!k 1:4 four step RK

     do while (k.le.4) 

!Set boundary conditions

        !write (*,*) NTIME, U(1,1)
!=========================== SOMETHING happens as soon as NTIME = 56, and from k = 1 to k = 2. molis k = 2 xtypaei NaN, sto k = 1 den xtypaei ==============================================================================================================================================
!if (NTIME .eq. 56 .and. k .eq. 2) then
   !write (*,*) NTIME, U(1:3,0:NXC+1)
!endif
        call bc

   !write (*,*) 'U is', U(1:3,0:NXC+1)

        cell_flux=0.d0

!For all Faces

        do i=1,NX
        
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) i, U(1:3,i)
  !endif
  
           !Left cell

           UCL = U(1:3,i-1)  
                 
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) i, UCL
  !endif
  
           !Right cell

           UCR = U(1:3,i)        

           !Get primitive variables
           
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) 'UCL(1) is', UCL(1)
  !endif

           call co_to_pri(UCL,UPL,Sf(i))

           call co_to_pri(UCR,UPR,Sf(i))

           NORM=1

           !calculate Roe-flux

           call calc_flux(UPL, UPR, UCL, UCR,NORM,Flux)

           !Normal points from left to right

           !For bc's it's obsolete

           cell_flux(1:3,i-1) = cell_flux(1:3,i-1)  + Flux  

           cell_flux(1:3,i)   = cell_flux(1:3,i)    - Flux

        enddo

!    Time integration

       if(k.eq.1) U0(1:3,1:NXC)=U(1:3,1:NXC)
       do i=1,NXC
        P(i) = GAMM1 * (U(3,i) - 0.5d0 / U(1,i) * U(2,i)**2/Sf(i))
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) 'P vector is ', P(i)
  !endif
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) 'U matrix is ', U(1:3,i)
  !endif
  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) i, U(1,i)
  !endif
        U(1:3,i) = U0(1:3,i) - DT/DX *rkconst(k)*(cell_flux(1:3,i) - cell_flux(1:3,i-1))
        U(2,i) = U(2,i) + (DT*P(i))*Scp(i)
       enddo
        k=k+1

     enddo
!if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.540E-4) then
   !write (*,*) 'Umatrix is ', U(1:3,1:NX)
!endif
     TIME = TIME + DT

     !write(*,*) 'NTIME= ',NTIME,'TIME= ', TIME

!write results 

     if (mod(NTIME,100).eq.0) call writeres(TIME)

  enddo

contains

!Set initial conditions

Subroutine ic

 Implicit None

 double precision :: UC(3),UP(3)

!Sod's shock tube initial conditions

! set pressure, velocity, density and then transform to conservative
       
 UP(3)= 3.3E5; UP(2) = 0.d0; UP(1) = UP(3)/(R*T0);

 do i=1,NXC

       call pri_to_co(UC,UP,Sf(i))

       U(1:3,i) = UC(1:3)

   !write (*,*) 'initial matrix is ', U(1:3,i)
   !write (*,*) NTIME, U(1,1)

 enddo

End Subroutine ic

!Set boundary conditions at ends

Subroutine bc

double precision :: UP(3),UC(3)

!give bc in a primitive form 

!start

 UP(1) =   4E5/(R*T0) !Density

 UP(2) =  U(2,1)/U(1,1) !Velocity

 UP(3) =   4E5   !Pressure
 
 !write (*,*) 'UP is', UP(1:3)
 
  !if (UP(2) .gt. 374) then
   !write (*,*) NTIME, UP(1:3)
  !endif

 call pri_to_co(UC,UP,Sc(0))

 U(1,0) =  UC(1) !Density

 U(2,0) =  UC(2) !Velocity

 U(3,0) =  UC(3) !Pressure

!end

 UP(1) =  U(1,NXC)/(conK+conA*((2-conC)**2)*((2-conC)**2-conB**2)) !Density

 UP(2) =  U(2,NXC)/U(1,NXC) !Velocity

 UP(3) =  3.2e5     !Pressure

 call pri_to_co(UC,UP,Sc(NXC+1))

 U(1,NXC+1) =  UC(1) !Density

 U(2,NXC+1) =  UC(2) !Velocity

 U(3,NXC+1) =  UC(3) !Pressure

end Subroutine bc

!write results in primitive variable form

Subroutine writeres(TIME)

double precision :: TIME,UP(3),UC(3)

  open (1,file='results.dat')

  write(1,'(a)') '#Time, X, Density, Velocity, Pressure'

  do i=1,NXC

     UC(1:3) = U(1:3,i)

     call co_to_pri(UC,UP,Sc(i))

     write(1,'(5(e28.17,1x))') TIME,XMIN + (i-1) * DX + 0.5 * DX, UP(1:3)

  enddo

  write(1,*) 

End Subroutine writeres

! Flux:Calculated Roe flux

Subroutine calc_flux(UPL, UPR, UCL, UCR,NORM,Flux)
use constants

  Implicit None

  double precision, intent(in)  :: UPL(3), UPR(3),UCL(3),UCR(3),NORM

  double precision, intent(out) :: Flux(3)

  double precision              :: Flux_left(3), Flux_right(3), Aroe(3,3), DF1(3)

!1D fluxes

  call flux1d(UPL,UCL,NORM,Flux_left,Sf(i))

  call flux1d(UPR,UCR,NORM,Flux_right,Sf(i))

!Roe matrix

  !if (TIME .gt. 0.539E-4 .and. TIME .lt. 0.54E-4) then
   !write (*,*) 'UPL(1) matrix is ', UPL(1)
  !endif

  call roematrix(UPL,UCL,UPR,UCR,NORM,Aroe,Sf(i))

  DF1(1:3) = UCR(1:3)-UCL(1:3)

!Final flux 

 Flux(1 : 3) = 0.5d0 * (Flux_left(1:3) + Flux_right(1:3) - matmul(Aroe,DF1))

End subroutine calc_flux

End Program Euler1d

!==============================================================================

!Subroutine to  convert conservative (UC) to primitive (UP)

Subroutine co_to_pri(UC,UP,S)

  use ieee_arithmetic, only: ieee_is_nan

  use constants

  Implicit None

  double precision, intent(in)  :: UC(3),S

  double precision, intent(out) :: UP(3)

  UP(1) = UC(1)/S

  UP(2) = UC(2)/UC(1)

  UP(3) = GAMM1 * (UC(3) - 0.5d0 / UC(1) * UC(2)**2)/S
  
    !write(*,*) 'error is',UC(1)

End Subroutine co_to_pri

!Subroutine to  convert primitive(UP) to conservative (UC)

Subroutine pri_to_co(UC,UP,S)

  use constants

  Implicit None

  double precision, intent(out)  :: UC(3)

  double precision, intent(in)   :: UP(3),S

  UC(1) = UP(1)*S

  UC(2) = UP(2)*UP(1)*S

  UC(3) = (UP(3) / GAMM1 + 0.5d0 * UP(1) * UP(2)**2)*S

End Subroutine pri_to_co

!Subroutine to calculate Roe flux

! UPL :Primitive Variable left 

! UPR :Primitive Variable right

! UCL :Conservative Variable left

! UCR :Conservative Variable Right

! NORM:Normal

!1D euler equaations flux functions

! UP :Primitive Variable

! UC :Conservative Variable 

! NORM:Normal

Subroutine flux1d(UP,UC,NORM,Flux,S)

  Implicit None

  double precision, intent(in)  :: UP(3), UC(3),NORM, S

  double precision, intent(out) :: Flux(3)

  double precision :: VN

  VN =  UP(2) * NORM

  Flux(1) = UP(1) * VN * S

  Flux(2) = (UP(1) * UP(2)* VN + UP(3) * NORM) * S

  Flux(3) = (UC(3) + UP(3)) * VN * S

End subroutine flux1d

!Subroutine to calculate Roe matrix

! UPL :Primitive Variable left 

! UPR :Primitive Variable right

! UCL :Conservative Variable left

! UCR :Conservative Variable Right

! NORM:Normal

! Aroe: ROe matrix in conservative variables

Subroutine roematrix(UPL,UCL,UPR,UCR,NORM,Aroe,S)

  use ieee_arithmetic, only: ieee_is_nan
  
  use constants

  Implicit None

  double precision, intent(in)  :: UPL(3),UCL(3),UPR(3),UCR(3),NORM, S

  double precision, intent(out) :: Aroe(3,3)

  double precision              :: DensRoe, Uroe, Hl,Hr, Hroe,croe,L1,L2,L3,delta

  double precision              :: left(3,3),right(3,3),eigen(3,3)

!Calculate Roe averaged variables (Density,Velocity,Enthalpy)

  DensRoe = sqrt(UPL(1))*sqrt(UPR(1))
  
  Uroe    = (sqrt(UPL(1)) * UPL(2) + sqrt(UPR(1)) * UPR(2)) / ( sqrt(UPL(1)) + sqrt(UPR(1)) )

  Hl     = (UCL(3)/S + UPL(3))/UPL(1)

  Hr     = (UCR(3)/S + UPR(3))/UPR(1)

  Hroe    = (sqrt(UPL(1)) * Hl + sqrt(UPR(1)) * Hr) / ( sqrt(UPL(1)) + sqrt(UPR(1)) )

  croe    =  sqrt( GAMM1 * (Hroe - 0.5d0 * Uroe**2) )
  
  !if (ieee_is_nan(croe)) then
  
     !write (*,*) UPL(1), UPL(2)
     
  !endif

!Get left and right eigenvectors in conservative form

  call leftrightcons(DensRoe,croe,Uroe,left,right)

  eigen     = 0.d0

   L1=abs(Uroe)

   L2=abs(Uroe+croe)

   L3=abs(Uroe-croe)

!Harten's entropy fix  and fill eigenvalue matrix

   delta = 0.05*croe

   if (L1.le.delta) L1 = (L1**2 + delta**2) / (2 * delta)

   if (L2.le.delta) L2 = (L2**2 + delta**2) / (2 * delta)

   if (L3.le.delta) L3 = (L3**2 + delta**2) / (2 * delta)

   eigen=0

   eigen(1,1)= L1

   eigen(2,2)= L2

   eigen(3,3)= L3

!get Roe matrix

   Aroe = matmul(right,eigen)

   Aroe = matmul(Aroe,left)

End Subroutine roematrix

!Subroutine to calculate left and right eigenvectors in conservative form

Subroutine leftrightcons(Dens,C,U,left,right)

   use constants

   Implicit None

   double precision, intent(in) :: Dens,U,C

   double precision, intent(out):: left(3,3),right(3,3)

   left(1,1) =  1.d0 - 0.5d0 * GAMM1 * U**2/C**2

   left(1,2) =  GAMM1 * U /C**2

   left(1,3) = -GAMM1/C**2

   left(2,1) = (0.5d0*GAMM1*U**2 - U*C) * (1.d0/(Dens*C))

   left(2,2) = (C - GAMM1*U) *(1.d0/(Dens*C))

   left(2,3) = GAMM1/(Dens*C)

   left(3,1) = -(0.5d0*GAMM1*U**2 + U*C) * (1.d0/(Dens*C))

   left(3,2) = (C + GAMM1*U) *(1.d0/(Dens*C))

   left(3,3) = -GAMM1/(Dens*C)

   right(1,1) =  1.d0

   right(1,2) =  0.5d0 * Dens/C

   right(1,3) = -0.5d0 * Dens/C
   
   right(2,1) = U

   right(2,2) = 0.5d0 * (U+C) * Dens/C

   right(2,3) =-0.5d0 * (U-C) * Dens/C

   right(3,1) = 0.5d0 * U**2

   right(3,2) = (0.5d0 * U**2 + U*C + C**2/GAMM1) * 0.5d0 * Dens/C

   right(3,3) =-(0.5d0 * U**2 - U*C + C**2/GAMM1) * 0.5d0 * Dens/C

End Subroutine leftrightcons

!==============================================================================
```

This code supposedly should work fine, and write the file results.dat with the expected results for density, velocity and pressure. However, at some point there is a NaN value appearing somewhere, it affects all following calculations and the results.dat file collapses full of NaN values at the end. With a bit of searching, the first appearance of NaN is probably around the NTIME = 53, k = 2 iteration or NTIME = 54, k = 2. Also, I have been told by others that at some point the argument of the square root in the calculation of croe (at line 486) is negative. My knowledge of fortran and debugging is very limited, and I do not have the time to learn now as I am reporting this very soon. If anyone has any ideas, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to run your code and it fell over at the line ```write(2,'(6(e28.17,1x))') i, xf(i), xc(i), Sf(i), Sc(i), Scp(i)``` where you try to write an integer with floating-point format.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Use the debugging features of your compiler. In gfortran use `-g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wall -ffpe-trap=zero,overflow,invalid`. Then re-run your code. For other compilers there are similar options. Tell us how you compile and test your code.

Comment: @Γεώργιος Γιουρούκος, you might want to explain your actual physical problem; also, what some of your large arrays are. What are your inlet/outlet boundary conditions and where are they set? Finally, do you need to do CFD to calculate 1-d Euler flow through a convergent-divergent nozzle?

Comment: If the arguments of your square root become negative due to some unwanted oscillations from your numerical scheme, you have to clip to values and make them nonnegative. This is quite a common thing with Euler equations. Even if the numerical scheme is theoretically positive, nonlinearities and rounding errors will cause slightly negative values and you have to get rid of them.

Comment: You don't have time to learn and you're reporting on your results.  This seems a bit concerning.

Comment: To explain more precisely: Air as a compressible fluid flows through a double convergent-divergent nozzle, the Sf and Sc vectors are the area of the cross section of the nozzle calculated at the faces or cells of my computational grid respectively. The large arrays U, UP, UC are the ones that store the main variables of the problem, first row is density, second is velocity and third is pressure. UC are the conservative variables (used to solve the equations) and UP refers to the primitive variables. The boundary conditions are set inside the bc subroutine and are given our  project briefing.

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation. Can you provide any link to the problem? Your boundary conditions appear to be fixed pressure, temperature and velocity at inlet, fixed pressure at outlet - probably OK. Where does this version of Runge-Kutta come from? Those aren't constants that I recognise. When I run your code it very quickly produces negative velocity within your domain - that's physically impossible. Can you try initialising it with a pressure that reflects your inlet (not outlet) pressure and a constant mass flux (not zero velocity).

Comment: @lastchance boundary conditions are indeed pressure, velocity and temperature, but temperature is used to calculate initial density eventually. The boundary conditions and also the initial conditions are provided in the project briefing, I am afraid I cannot provide it, sorry for that. The runge-kutta constants are also provided by the briefing, so no idea. I have run it a few times with larger initial velocities and also with initial pressure equal to the inlet, with no dramatic change in the result file  (even though we are asked to initialize with the specific values I have provided above).

Comment: I've been fiddling with the code quite a bit. I've reduced the output frequency to see more clearly what is happening. Problems seem to start mainly at inflow, where there is a rapidly rising velocity; eventually it exceeds the speed of sound and your code breaks down. How did your briefing advise you to handle the inflow boundary condition?

Comment: So in the inflow we are asked to apply fixed pressure and density (temperature). Pressure is given and equal to 4 bar, because that is the pressure inside the air reservoir where the flow begins. Temperature is irrelevant as far as they've told us, I set it equal to the temperature of initial conditions (276K). For the velocity, we are advised to set it equal to the velocity of the first internal cell. To be clear, the grid (1D) consists of NX faces and NX - 1 cell centers between them. There are 2 ghost cells outside, one for the inlet, one for the outlet, and bc calculates those 2 cells. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some major errors.

The biggest problem is where you subtract fluxes in the time integration `cell_flux(1:3,i) - cell_flux(1:3,i-1)`. Array cell_flux() ALREADY holds the flux divergence for that cell: you don't need to subtract again.

You also have errors in the expressions for P(i) and Flux(3).

I'm afraid that I had to refactor your code quite a lot to read it. So here's a version that runs. You may have to increase NTIMETOT to approach the steady solution, but it appears to show the formation of a shock near the exit. Both boundary-condition arrangements could be improved, I think.

I haven't changed your timestepping routine (because I don't recognise it), nor your Roe flux (because it's too long since I dealt with Riemann solvers and I've also mislaid Phil Roe's paper).

```
module constants

   double precision, parameter :: GAM = 1.4, GAMM1 = GAM - 1         ! ratio of specific heats
   double precision, parameter :: R = 287.05                         ! ideal gas constant for air
   double precision, parameter :: T0 = 276.0                         ! static temperature (K)
   double precision, parameter :: rkconst(4) = [ 0.1084d0, 0.2602d0, 0.5052d0, 1.0d0 ]

   double precision, allocatable :: xc(:), Sc(:)
   double precision, allocatable :: xf(:), Sf(:)

end module constants

!===============================================================================

program Euler1d
   use constants
   implicit none
   double precision, external :: area
   double precision, allocatable :: U(:,:), U0(:,:), cell_flux(:,:), P(:)
   double precision XMIN, XMAX, DX, DT,TIME
   double precision UCL(3), UCR(3), UPL(3), UPR(3), Flux(3)
   double precision NORM
   integer NX, NXC, NTIME, NTIMETOT
   integer i, k

   ! Input Parameters
   NTIMETOT = 50000           ! Total timesteps (needs to be raised to at least 10 times this)
   DT = 1.0E-6
   XMIN = 0.0;   XMAX = 2.0
   DX = 0.01

   ! Number of nodes and faces
   NX = int( ( XMAX - XMIN ) / DX )         ! Number of faces
   DX = ( XMAX - XMIN ) / ( NX - 1 )        ! Calculate new DX for accurate division by NX
   NXC = NX - 1                             ! Number of interior cell centers

   ! 0: represents ghost cell at inflow and NXC+1 ghost cell at end
   ! U is the solution vector [density * area, density * velocity * area, density * energy * area ],
   ! U0 is the vector after the 1st Runge-Kutta step
   ! Cell_flux is the NET FLUX OUT OF A CELL
   allocate( U(3,0:NXC+1), U0(3,0:NXC+1), P(0:NXC+1), xc(0:NXC+1), Sc(0:NXC+1) )
   allocate( cell_flux(1:3,0:NXC+1) )
   allocate( xf(1:NX), Sf(1:NX) )

   ! Set locations and areas
   do i = 1, NX
      xf(i) = XMIN + ( i - 1 ) * DX
      xc(i) = xf(i) + DX / 2
      Sf(i) = area( xf(i) )
      Sc(i) = area( xc(i) )
   end do
   xc(0   )  = xc(1 ) - DX
   xc(NX+1)  = xc(NX) + DX
   Sc(0)     = Sc(1)
   Sc(NXC+1) = Sc(NXC)

   ! Set initial conditions
   TIME = 0
   call ic

   ! Timestepping
   do NTIME = 1, NTIMETOT

      do k = 1, 4                      ! four-step RK
         ! Set boundary conditions
         call bc

         ! Calculate net fluxes from cells 1 to NXC (=NX-1)
         cell_flux = 0

         do i = 1, NX
            ! Left/right cells
            UCL = U(:,i-1)
            UCR = U(:,i)

            ! Get primitive variables
            call co_to_pri( UCL, UPL, Sc(i-1) )
            call co_to_pri( UCR, UPR, Sc(i  ) )

            ! Normal points from left to right
            NORM = 1

            ! Calculate flux on cell face
            call calc_flux( UPL, UPR, UCL, UCR, NORM, Flux )

            ! Compound the fluxes OUT of adjacent cells
            cell_flux(:,i-1) = cell_flux(:,i-1) + Flux
            cell_flux(:,i  ) = cell_flux(:,i  ) - Flux

         end do

         ! Time integration
         if( k == 1 ) U0 = U
         do i = 1, NXC
            P(i) = GAMM1 * ( U(3,i) - 0.5 * U(2,i) ** 2  / U(1,i) ) / Sc(i)
            U(:,i) = U0(:,i) - DT / DX * rkconst(k) * cell_flux(:,i)           ! d(U)/dt = -d(F)/dx
            U(2,i) = U(2,i) + DT * P(i) * ( Sf(i+1) - Sf(i) ) / DX             ! effect of side-wall expansion
         end do
      end do
      TIME = TIME + DT

      if ( mod( NTIME, 100 ) == 0 ) call writeres( TIME )

  end do

contains

   ! Set initial conditions
   subroutine ic
      implicit None
      double precision :: UP(3)
      integer i

      ! Set pressure, velocity, density
      UP(3) = 3.3e5                    ! pressure
      UP(1) = UP(3) / ( R * T0 )       ! density
      UP(2) = 0                        ! velocity

      ! Transform to conservative variables
      do i = 0, NXC + 1
         call pri_to_co( U(:,i), UP, Sc(i) )
      end do

   end subroutine ic

   !----------------------------------------------

   subroutine bc
      double precision UP(3)

      ! Inlet
      UP(3) = 4e5                           ! pressure
      UP(1) = UP(3) / ( R * T0 )            ! density (based on pressure and temperature)
      UP(2) = U(2,1) / U(1,1)               ! velocity (extrapolated from interior)
      call pri_to_co( U(:,0), UP, Sc(0) )

      ! Outlet
      UP(3) = 3.2e5                         ! pressure
      UP(1) = U(1,NXC) / Sc(NXC)            ! density (extrapolated from interior)
      UP(2) = U(2,NXC) / U(1,NXC)           ! velocity (extrapolated from interior)
      call pri_to_co( U(:,NXC+1), UP, Sc(NXC+1) )

   end subroutine bc

   !----------------------------------------------

   subroutine writeres( TIME )
      double precision, intent(in) :: TIME
      double precision UP(3)
      integer i

      open( 10, file="results.dat" )
!     write( 10, "(a)" ) "#Time, X, Density, Velocity, Pressure"
      do i = 0, NXC + 1
         call co_to_pri( U(:,i), UP, Sc(i) )
         write( 10, "( 5( e13.6, 1x ) )" ) TIME, xc(i), UP
      end do
      close( 10 )

   end subroutine writeres

   !----------------------------------------------

   ! Calculated flux
   subroutine calc_flux( UPL, UPR, UCL, UCR, NORM, Flux )
      use constants
      implicit None
      double precision, intent(in)  :: UPL(3), UPR(3), UCL(3), UCR(3), NORM
      double precision, intent(out) :: Flux(3)
      double precision Flux_left(3), Flux_right(3), ARoe(3,3)

      ! 1D fluxes
      call flux1d( UPL, UCL, NORM, Flux_left , Sc(i) )
      call flux1d( UPR, UCR, NORM, Flux_right, Sc(i) )

      ! Roe matrix
      call Roematrix( UPL, UCL, UPR, UCR, ARoe, Sf(i) )
      Flux = 0.5 * ( Flux_left + Flux_right - matmul( ARoe, UCR - UCL ) )

   end subroutine calc_flux

end program Euler1d

!===============================================================================

! Function returning cross-sectional area
double precision function area( x )
   double precision, intent(in) :: x
   double precision, parameter :: conA = 0.408, conB= 0.93, conC= 1.07, conK= 0.17

   area = conK + conA * ( ( x - conC ) ** 2 ) * ( ( x - conC ) ** 2 - conB **2 )

end function area

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! Convert conservative (UC) to primitive (UP) variables
subroutine co_to_pri( UC, UP, S )
  use constants
  implicit none
  double precision, intent(in ) :: UC(3), S
  double precision, intent(out) :: UP(3)

  UP(1) = UC(1) / S                                             ! density
  UP(2) = UC(2) / UC(1)                                         ! velocity
  UP(3) = GAMM1 * ( UC(3) - 0.5 * UC(2) ** 2 / UC(1) ) / S      ! pressure

end subroutine co_to_pri

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! Convert primitive(UP) to conservative (UC)
subroutine pri_to_co( UC, UP, S )
  use constants
  implicit none
  double precision, intent(out) :: UC(3)
  double precision, intent(in ) :: UP(3), S

  UC(1) = UP(1) * S                                             ! density * area
  UC(2) = UP(2) * UP(1) * S                                     ! density * velocity * area
  UC(3) = ( UP(3) / GAMM1 + 0.5 * UP(1) * UP(2) ** 2 ) * S      ! volumetric internal energy * area

end subroutine pri_to_co

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! Calculate flux vector
subroutine flux1d( UP, UC, NORM, Flux, S )
  implicit none
  double precision, intent(in ) :: UP(3), UC(3), NORM, S
  double precision, intent(out) :: Flux(3)
  double precision VN

  VN =  UP(2) * NORM
  Flux(1) = UP(1) * VN * S                    
  Flux(2) = ( UP(1) * UP(2) * VN + UP(3) ) * S
  Flux(3) = ( UC(3) + UP(3) * S ) * VN

end subroutine flux1d

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! Calculate Roe matrix
subroutine Roematrix( UPL, UCL, UPR, UCR, Aroe, S)
   use constants
   implicit none
   double precision, intent(in ) :: UPL(3), UCL(3), UPR(3), UCR(3), S
   double precision, intent(out) :: ARoe(3,3)
   double precision densRoe, uRoe, hl, hr, hRoe, cRoe, L1, L2, L3, delta
   double precision left(3,3), right(3,3), eigen(3,3)
   double precision fl, fr

   ! Calculate Roe-averaged variables
   fl = sqrt( UPL(1) );   fr = sqrt( UPR(1) )
   densRoe = fl * fr
   uRoe    = ( fl * UPL(2) + fr * UPR(2) ) / ( fl + fr )
   hl      = ( UCL(3) / S + UPL(3) ) / UPL(1)
   hr      = ( UCR(3) / S + UPR(3) ) / UPR(1)
   hRoe    = ( fl * hl + fr * hr ) / ( fl + fr )
   cRoe    =  sqrt( GAMM1 * ( hRoe - 0.5 * uRoe **2 ) )

   ! Get left and right eigenvectors in conservative form
   call leftrightcons( densRoe, cRoe, uRoe, left, right )
   eigen = 0
   L1 = abs( uRoe        )
   L2 = abs( uRoe + cRoe )
   L3 = abs( Uroe - cRoe )
   ! Harten's entropy fix  and fill eigenvalue matrix
   delta = 0.05 * cRoe
   if ( L1 <= delta ) L1 = ( L1 ** 2 + delta ** 2 ) / ( 2 * delta )
   if ( L2 <= delta ) L2 = ( L2 ** 2 + delta ** 2 ) / ( 2 * delta )
   if ( L3 <= delta ) L3 = ( L3 ** 2 + delta ** 2 ) / ( 2 * delta )
   eigen = 0
   eigen(1,1) = L1
   eigen(2,2) = L2
   eigen(3,3) = L3
   ARoe = matmul( right, eigen )
   ARoe = matmul( ARoe , left  )

end subroutine Roematrix

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

! Calculate left and right eigenvectors in conservative form
subroutine leftrightcons( dens, c, u, left, right )
   use constants
   implicit none
   double precision, intent(in) :: dens, u, c
   double precision, intent(out):: left(3,3), right(3,3)

   left(1,1)  =  1 - 0.5 * GAMM1 * u ** 2 / c ** 2
   left(1,2)  =  GAMM1 * u / c ** 2
   left(1,3)  = -GAMM1 / c ** 2
   left(2,1)  = ( 0.5 * GAMM1 * u ** 2 - u * c ) / ( dens * c )
   left(2,2)  = ( c - GAMM1 * u ) / ( dens * c )
   left(2,3)  = GAMM1 / ( dens * c )
   left(3,1)  = -( 0.5 * GAMM1 * u ** 2 + u * c ) / ( dens * c )
   left(3,2)  = ( c + GAMM1 * u ) / ( dens * c )
   left(3,3)  = -GAMM1 / ( dens * c )
   right(1,1) =  1
   right(1,2) =  0.5 * dens / c
   right(1,3) = -0.5 * dens / c
   right(2,1) = u
   right(2,2) = 0.5 * ( u + c ) * dens / c
   right(2,3) =-0.5 * ( u - c ) * dens / c
   right(3,1) = 0.5 * u ** 2
   right(3,2) = ( 0.5 * u ** 2 + u * c + c ** 2 / GAMM1 ) * 0.5 * dens / c
   right(3,3) =-( 0.5 * u ** 2 - u * c + c ** 2 / GAMM1 ) * 0.5 * dens / c

end subroutine leftrightcons

!==============================================================================
```

I get the following pressure plot. There appears to be a shock just before the exit. Where, and how big, this is depends on your inlet and outlet pressures.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has been critical. I need one last thing, make a video showing the pressure and local mach during the time steps. I have added the local mach in my code. In other words, I need to make a script (maybe .sh?)which makes 2 plots in each time step. 1st plot using 2:5 (pressure), 2nd plot using 2:6 (local mach) from results.dat. I have searched a bit but can't find the correct way/syntax to make a plot for each specific value of column 1 of results.dat. For example, first time step: 2 plots for column1=DT, next time step: 2 plots for column1=2*DT etc. Hope it's all clear. TY!

Comment: @Γεώργιος Γιουρούκος, as my code stands it will overwrite results.dat each time that it backs up. You can amend it to append to that file instead, if you wish, but the resulting file will be very long. However, if you are making a video I suggest that each output time you write to a DIFFERENT FILE - so results.1, results.2, results.3, etc. You can then batch script gnuplot or Python/matplotlib etc to produce a plot at each time and then stitch the still pictures together with something like imageMagic. Alternatively, Python can produce animations directly.